# Tracking simultaneous events

Tags: python

I am tracking the change of value at a particular time in an array ('x' is an array with the value, x_time is an array with corresponding change of time associted with values in 'x[]').

```
x = []
x_time = []
```

*Output Example:*

```
x = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
x_time = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

How do I trace the simultaneous events in the time array? I want only 1 event to occur at 1 second, but 3 events are taking place. I want to track the number of multiple transactions in the array.

How to trace the duplicate events? Is there a module that I can import? is there a data structure which helps me tracking duplicates?

*Expected outcome:* Number of duplicate events in x_time[] = 2.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  You haven't explained what results you expect, nor the algorithm you're trying to implement.  Also, you haven't posted your coding attempt and the problematic output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicates can be traced with 'set' data structures.

```
x = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
x_time = [1,1,1,2,3]

#remove duplicates
dup_x_time = set(x_time)
dup_len = len(dup_x_time)

new_x_time = len(x_time)
Duplicates = (new_x_time - dup_len )

print(Duplicates)
```